# How to create thread specific memory appender in NLog

Tags: c#, log4net, nlog

I am pasting my code snippet using log4Net,

-Just in brief:

I am creating a new rolling appender and a memory appender and attaching them to a logger in logger repository for every new thread.

Whatever I write in rolling appender, automatically got in memory appender of specific thread.

I want to achieve same using NLog

I tried NLog but I got two behaviour

1. all file targets writing into same memory target, not thread specific target.
2. After setting new appender everything is getting written in new appender.

   ```
   class Program {
   private static Random rnd = new Random();
   private static object sync = new object();

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
       // Execute the task 10 times.
       for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 5; ctr++)
       {
           tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(FirstWorldTask));
           Thread.Sleep(10);
       }
       Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
   }

   private static void FirstWorldTask()
   {
       string loggerName = "Logger";
       string randomName = rnd.Next().ToString();

       lock (sync)
       {
           loggerName += randomName;
           Console.WriteLine(loggerName);
       }

       log4net.Layout.PatternLayout patternLayout = new log4net.Layout.PatternLayout("%message%newline");
       patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

       RollingFileAppender rollingFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender();
       rollingFileAppender.AppendToFile = false;
       rollingFileAppender.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size;
       rollingFileAppender.MaxSizeRollBackups = 0;
       rollingFileAppender.MaximumFileSize = "20MB";
       rollingFileAppender.Layout = patternLayout;
       rollingFileAppender.File = "./" + randomName + "/logfile.txt";
       //appender.File = GlobalSettings.FOLDER_NAME + "logfile" + currentCount.ToString() + ".txt";
       rollingFileAppender.ActivateOptions();

       MemoryAppender memoryAppender = new MemoryAppender();
       memoryAppender.AddFilter(new log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter() { LevelMin = log4net.Core.Level.Info, LevelMax = log4net.Core.Level.Fatal });

       log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy hierarchy = (log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)log4net.LogManager.GetRepository();
       log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger logger = hierarchy.GetLogger(loggerName) as log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger;

       logger.AddAppender(rollingFileAppender);
       logger.AddAppender(memoryAppender);
       hierarchy.Configured = true;

       var m_log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(loggerName);


       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       {
           m_log.Info(i + " " + randomName);
           Thread.Sleep(10);
       }

       StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
       foreach (var loggingEvent in memoryAppender.GetEvents())
       {
           stringBuilder.AppendLine(loggingEvent.MessageObject.ToString());
       }

       memoryAppender.Clear();
       Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString());
   }
   ```

   }

NLog Config:

```
    <target name="LogFile"
            xsi:type="File"
            fileName="${mdc:item=LogsDirectory}/logfile.txt"
            layout="${message}"
            maxArchiveFiles="10"
            archiveAboveSize="20000000"
            archiveNumbering="Sequence"
            archiveFileName="${mdc:item=LogsDirectory}/logfile.{#}.txt"/>
    <target name="Memory" xsi:type="Memory" layout="${message}"/>

  <rules>
    <logger name="LogFile" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="LogFile" />
    <logger name="LogFile" minlevel="Info" writeTo="Memory" />
</rules>
```

NLog Code for FirstWorldTask

```
    private static void FirstWorldTask()
    {
        var folderName = rnd.Next();
        NLog.MappedDiagnosticsContext.Set("LogsDirectory", folderName);
        ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger("LogFile");
        var memoryTarget = (MemoryTarget)NLog.LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("Memory");
        memoryTarget.Logs.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            logger.Info(i + " " + folderName);
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
        int j = 0;

        while (j < memoryTarget.Logs.Count)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(memoryTarget.Logs[j] + "\t" + folderName);
            memoryTarget.Logs.RemoveAt(j);

            j++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you've posted the code that works, but not the code that doesn't work?

Comment: this issue is now tracked at https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1598